# Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease' with -keep flag

Tags: android-studio, proguard

I hope someone can help with these specific build failures - I've seen all the SO threads and tried the main ones, my specific error:

```
Error:Warning: com.google.android.maps.MapView$Repainter: can't find superclass or interface android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestListener
Warning: com.google.android.maps.MapView$Repainter: can't find referenced class android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestListener
Warning: com.google.android.maps.MapView$Repainter: can't find referenced class android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequest
Warning: com.google.android.maps.ZoomHelper$Snapshot: can't find referenced class android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.map.Zoom
Warning: there were 4 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
     You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions.
     If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress
     the warnings with '-dontwarn' options.
     (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass)
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
```

> Job failed, see logs for details

My build file release section:

```
release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
```

So in proguard-rules.txt I've tried

```
-ignorewarnings
-keep class * {
public private *;
}
```

More specifically I've tried

```
 -keep public class com.google.android.gms.* { public *; }
 -dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
```

Neither of these seem to work - is there anything I can do to actually figure out if its even reading this proguard txt file ?

Any other suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it didn't take long but I went into Build -> Edit Build Types and in here I selected `release`, and manually selected my `proguard-rules.txt`, clicked OK and it basically added

```
proguardFile '.../StudioProjects/App/proguard-rules.txt'
```

which got the build to work successfully.